# How to access SD card as a external drive from a camera

Tags: macos

I'm using high sierra.

There's must be a way to treat a connected camera's SD card as external drive.

The image capture is not the option. Because I need to move a firmware file to the SD card and upgrade the camera.

Any idea to do that on Mac OS?

Comment: This is 100% dependent on the camera, and has nothing to do with what or how on a Mac. You didn’t specify your make and model of camera. The manual is where you should start.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is just a USB SD card reader. The reader plugs into the PC, the card plugs into the reader.

Is that what you're after?

Comment: You should clarify that the SDcard needs to be removed from the camera (since the OP has not even considered that option).